# How to use xcopy to only copy files if they are newer?

Tags: visual-studio, xcopy, post-build-event

I have many web applications in a Visual Studio solution.

All have the same post build command:

```
xcopy "$(TargetDir)*.dll" "D:\Project\bin" /i /d /y
```

It would be useful to avoid replacing newer files with old ones (e.g. someone could accidentally add a reference to an old version of a DLL).

How can I use xcopy to replace old files only with **newer DLL files** generated by Visual Studio?

Comment: [Is there a way to xcopy just changed or new files?](https://superuser.com/q/308277/241386)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From typing "help xcopy" at the command line:

```
/D:m-d-y     Copies files changed on or after the specified date.
             If no date is given, copies only those files whose
             source time is newer than the destination time.
```

So you already are using xcopy to only replace old files with new ones. If that's not happening, you may have to swap the positions of the `/i` and `/d` switches.

Answer (score 5):

User following command to copy all new and modified file from source to destination

xcopy c:\source d:\destination /D /I /E /Y

/D to check any modified file are there
/I If the destination does not exist and copying more than one file, assumes that destination must be a directory.
/E To copy directory and sub directories
/Y to suppress any over write prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but I use a similar command script for these sorts of tasks.

```
set DIR_DEST=D:\Project\bin
pushd "$(TargetDir)"

::
:: Move Files matching pattern and delete them
::
for %%g in (*.dll) do (xcopy "%%g" "%DIR_DEST%" /D /Y & del "%%g")

::
:: Move Files matching pattern
::
:: for %%g in (*.dll) do (xcopy "%%g" "%DIR_DEST%" /D /Y )

popd
```